# Is the following sentence a tautology: $(p\Rightarrow q)\vee(r \Rightarrow p)\vee(r\Rightarrow s)\vee(r\Rightarrow q)$?

Tags: boolean-algebra, propositional-calculus

If both $p$ and $q$ are false then ($p\Rightarrow q$) is true.
If either $p$ or $q$ is true  then one of ($r\Rightarrow p$) or ($r\Rightarrow q$) is true.
If both $p$ and $q$ are true then all are true.
Since they are OR'ed, one way of an other is true.
IT IS A TAUTOLOGY..

My prof dint accept my answer, he said need little more consideration.

Comment: If $p$ is true, then due to $r\to p$, the statement is true. If $p$ is false, due to $p\to q$ the statement is true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your professor is mistaken, and your argument is correct, though it could be simplified slightly without any major change, since you could combine the second and third cases:

> If $p$ and $q$ are both false, then $p\to q$ is true; otherwise at least one of $p$ and $q$ is true, and therefore at least one of $r\to p$ and $r\to q$ is true. In all cases, therefore, at least one of the implications is true and therefore their disjunction is true.

However, it can be simplified even more by looking just at $p$: if $p$ is true, then $r\to p$ is true, and if $p$ is false, then $p\to q$ is true.

Comment: p,q,r are logical sentences but what can i say about (r->s)            i mean how can i show it in truth table??

Comment: @sbrajagopal26: A truth table for the disjunction in the title of the question would have $16$ rows, one for each combination of **true** and **false** for $p,q,r$, and $s$, and it would have columns for $p,q,r,s,p\to q,r\to p,r\to s,r\to q$ and the whose expression. Just fill it in in the usual way. For instance, there will be four rows in which $r$ is **true** and $s$ is **false**, and in those four rows $r\to s$ will be **false**; in the other $12$ rows it will be **true**.

Answer (score 1):

$p \Rightarrow q$ is equivalent to $\neg p \lor q$.  So $(p\Rightarrow q)\vee(r \Rightarrow p)\vee(r\Rightarrow s)\vee(r\Rightarrow q)$ is equivalent to $(\neg p \lor q) \lor (\neg r \lor p) \lor (\text{others})$ which is equivalent to $\neg p \lor p \lor (\text{others})$ which is equivalent to $\top$.